# Listview only shows when EditText is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I am displaying a edittext outside of the listview in the same activity.  When the activity loads it wont show the listview until I click the EditText or if I turn the screen off and on and then it will display the listview.  I get this warning in my logcat "finishcomposingtext on inactive inputconnection" were it stops... I'm trying to get everything to display when the activity starts

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="button1"
                android:text="button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="button2"
                android:text="button2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
                android:onClick="button3"
                android:text="button3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="button4"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="button5"
                android:text="button5" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10" 
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" 
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I guess a piece of the layout would be useful?

Comment: I had same problem. just make sure you initialize or set list adapter after you've populated the array you will pass to the adapter not before you populate the array. `mAdapter = new MenutItemBaseAdapter(activity, populatedArray);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`  The above code shoudl happend after you have populated the array..